# Sphinx's .. include:: directive and "duplicate label" warnings

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm trying to use [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/)'s [`.. include::` directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#include) to include docs from one file in another file, to avoid duplicating the source text of the docs. The section I'm including is in `configuration.rst` (it's part of the reference docs for the config settings) and it contains some labels for cross-referencing each config setting:

```
.. start_config-authorization

.. _ckan.auth.anon_create_dataset:

ckan.auth.anon_create_dataset
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Example::

 ckan.auth.anon_create_dataset = False

Default value: ``False``

Allow users to create datasets without registering and logging in.


.. _ckan.auth.create_unowned_dataset:

ckan.auth.create_unowned_dataset
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

...

.. end_config-authorization
```

In another file (`authorization.rst`) I include just the authorization config settings from `configuration.rst` inline, like this:

```
.. include:: /configuration.rst
    :start-after: start_config-authorization
    :end-before: end_config-authorization
```

The problem is that the labels within the included text produce this warning from Sphinx:

```
doc/configuration.rst:224: WARNING: duplicate label ckan.auth.anon_create_dataset, other instance in doc/authorization.rst
```

So far cross-referencing doesn't seem to be broken, if I put:

```
:ref:`ckan.auth.anon_create_dataset`
```

in a third file, this correctly produces a link to the definition of `ckan.auth.anon_create_dataset` in `configuration.html` (and not the included copy of it in `authorization.html`).

Is it safe to simply ignore or silence these duplicate label warnings, and expect all cross-refs to link to `configuration.html`? Or should I find another way of doing this?

Comment: Nearly eight years later, this issue is still not fixed.

Answer (score 14):

There are two ways to solve this: switch to a different extension (*.inc), or add any include files to `exclude_patterns` in `conf.py`.

Comment: This seems to work. I changed the file extensions to *.rst.inc, to make it obvious that it is still a normal rst file.

Comment: @MaxPowers what do you think of my solution? You can keep the rst extension (and any IDE syntax checking) if you reverse it to be `*.inc.rst` and glob it in the exclude pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Want to add my solution to this:

```
.. include:: /configuration.inc.rst
```

Then glob in exclusions:

```
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store', '**/*inc.rst']
```

This allows you to keep the rst extension, you just need to rename the included rsts with a `.inc.rst` extension.

I'll just add, I think this is dumb default behavior and should be considered a bug not by design: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/7697

If it's by design the design should change because this seems to be a really common usage pattern and these useless warnings drown out actual syntax issues if you have a lot of rsts and are trying to parse through this in the build output.

Comment: Great solution! You can also just add a specific file if needed without even having .inc e.g. `exclude_patterns = ['my/foo.rst']`

Answer (score -1):

Safe to ignore? It will remain a warning but the original content seems to block the included labels so it shouldn't be too dangerous if you check it from time to time.

Have you tried putting the content in a file, not indexed with no label, include this file wherever you need it and create a file, indexed, with the label and include the unlabeled content? The last file should be pointed by references.

Ps: I haven't tested so the label might get crossed by the fact it's followed by an include and not standard content.

Comment: Not really. I think if a duplicate is detected it will be ignored. Either the reference will be without a link or the target won't be created or both.